# How to make title exact match appear first in search API

Tags: 7, search

For example,

I have content A with :

- title = Quick brown fox jumps
- body = (empty)

and then I have many other content with word 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', and 'jumps' all accross the body field.

I use govCms distribution profile.

#### What happen

When I search for content with title "Quick brown fox jumps", content A is displayed on rank 4th on 1st page.

#### What I expect

It should be rank 1st because it has exact match.

#### Module I use:

[Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api), [Search API page](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_page), [Search API Database Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_db)

#### What I try

1. I try to set *Influence* for *Content is promoted to front page* to 10, and make content A as promoted to front page. Clear index and build search index, but still no change.
2. I try to boost Title field (Type: Fulltext, Indexed: Checked) to 21.0, clear index and build search index, but also no change.

#### Question

How to make content with exact title to appear 1st?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this? I have the same issue

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm not in the project anymore, but last time I heard engine was switched to use solr, because requirement changed.